# how to call or run the function in JavaScript every time when we resize the window?

Tags: javascript, html, function

First of all thanks for reading my question.

I want to know that how can I call the function in the javascript each time I resize my window.

```
window.('resize', function(){
    thsis()

    console.log('it runs')

})

function thsis(){
    console.log('this ')
}
```

This code doesn't works for me by the console {console.log('it runs')
statement works with this but not which is in the function
I hope that you will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onresize = function(e){
    thsis();
}

function thsis()
{
  console.log("this");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `addEventListener`:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    thsis()

    console.log('it runs')

})

function thsis(){
    console.log('this ')
}
```